# Find Last 4 Max Number from Alphanumeric Vlues in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm working on a sheet in which i have to keep record of my cartridges used in machines. [image]

Every Machine use 4 cartridges at a time Marked as "In Use" in Data table. Now I'm trying to get all 4 "In Use" cartridges IDs of every machine separately in "In Use Cartridges" Table. I've tried many formulas but get only Max Value only. Please help me on this. Also i cant use VBA in my sheet just only need formula solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C4` copied across and down try this formula

`=INDEX($B$10:$B$29,AGGREGATE(14,6,(ROW($B$10:$B$29)-ROW($B$10)+1)/($C$10:$C$29=$A4)/($D$10:$D$29="In use"),COLUMNS($C4:C4)))`

`AGGREGATE` function finds the kth largest row where MC # matches and cartridge is in use, then `INDEX` function finds the ID for that row. `COLUMNS` function increments k as you copy across so you get the last 4 starting with the last

If column A always starts at 1 and increments by 1 you can shorten a little to this version

`=INDEX($B$10:$B$29,AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$10:$A$29/($C$10:$C$29=$A4)/($D$10:$D$29="In use"),COLUMNS($C4:C4)))`

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. I Really Appreciate your help. It works just as expected. Thank you so much.